# How to run a function after a given time in node.JS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, function

I am building a hosting server with node.JS and mongoDB.

The server will be used for people to save their files remotely. But I do not want to keep unattended files on the server because it will be a waste of memory on the server.

So there are two things I wish to do :

- Delete Files if not attended for more than 10 days
- Leave the Files otherwise

Is there a way this can be done easily?

Comment: you can create a cron job to periodically check and delete least recently used files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cron job for this type of scheduled task. NodeJS has a module named [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) to perform a scheduled task.

**Approach:**
Every day at midnight you will check for unattended files. If you find any unattended file then you can delete it.

**Example code:**

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('0 0 * * *', async () => {
    // Find files
    // Delete files
}, null, true, 'America/Vancouver', null, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will definitely try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a cron and it will check for your condition and do the desired action.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

example:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
job.start();
```